# Who fathered Claire Bennet's children in Heroes Reborn

Tags: heroes-reborn

Given that Claire Bannet must have conceived 9 months before "June 13th" (the previous August or September) during the 5 year hiatus, is there any indication of who is the biological father.

This was the only reference to the children's descent that I could find.

> In "June 13 - Part 2", Angela realizes how Claire died: the new born
>   Nathan has the same power absorption abilities that his
>   great-grandfather Arthur Petrelli and to a lesser extent his
>   grand-uncle Peter had. While still an infant, he took Claire's powers
>   which allowed her to die during the childbirth. However, as Nathan can
>   only keep one ability at a time, unlike his great-grandfather, he lost
>   her abilities soon after her death when he took Hiro's power.

In the teaser after the end of the finale ("three months later") we see the first indication that Angela knows who the father is. We have seen no reference anywhere else.

Comment: It's been stated a number of times, do you not believe that or are looking for confirmation that it could have happened?

Comment: @blm I must have missed it. I have only been watching the shows and the only reference that I saw was to Nathan as Colaire's father (Nathan the infant having the power of a Petrelli).

Comment: Ok, I did a little research and I think I'm mistaken. At one point in a recent episode, Noah says something like "His [Nathan's] father is ...". However, I think Noah was just shortening step-father to father, not referring to Nathan's actual biological father. I didn't get that at the time but reading probably the same page you got the quote from, I see it now.

Comment: I don't think we know who the biological father is; I think the implication is that Claire had lost contact with most of her friends/family by June 13th; Noah didn't even seen to know she was pregnant.

Comment: @blm I think that you are referring to the "His father is Hiro" line. I also took it to mean that until we saw Hiro get "stuck" with Nathan in 1999. Perhaps they will bring it up in the future. I also saw that they never showed Noah seeing Claire's face and the indication from the security tapes that there was significant time travel activity in the morgue (that has not yet been actually shown).

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. I agree, there are a lot of open questions yet.

Comment: Gretchen, probably

Comment: Unfortunately, one reason for not seeing Claire's face might simply be that Hayden Panettiere can't return to the show. In any case, I think we all know that Sylar is Malina and Tommy's father.... ;)

Comment: @Jonah Not necessarily, though it is possible based on the way things were presented during the original series. I would suspect that they may have come up with explanations that fit within the story line.

Comment: Why can't HP return to the show?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Because she was written out as dead in the first episode. Of course, it is possible that they can rewrite it as Noah never having uncovered her face and have Nathan (her son) grab her body after we have last seen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The father of Claire's children was a man whom Claire nicknamed "Hammer."  Very little is known about him.  According to the tie-in novel, [Heroes Reborn - Book 5: Save the Cheerleader, Destroy the World](http://heroeswiki.com/Save_the_Cheerleader,_Destroy_the_World), Claire and Hammer met in June of 2012.  Claire had been working with Peter Petrelli, Mohinder Suresh, Micah Sanders and others who had gone underground to help Evos struggling against increasing repression and prejudice.  On June 5th, Hammer arrived on the barge where the movement was headquartered.  He was unconscious and in bad shape, after nearly being lynched in Monaco along with seven other Evos.  Claire chose to call him "Hammer" for his "stupid" trench coat, in reference to Mickey Spillane's Mike Hammer books she'd been reading.  On July 4th of that year, Claire and Hammer became romantically entangled, sharing their first kiss.  But Hammer grew increasingly moody and agitated, expressing a desire to be more "proactive" in the struggle for Evo justice.  Eventually, he simply left without a word.

In September of 2013, Claire and Hammer reunited unexpectedly in an abbey in northern Italy, where Claire had taken safe haven.  They rekindled their romance, and conceived the twins, Nathan (Tommy) and Malina.  The next day, Hammer was gone, again without a word.  A few days later, Claire awoke feeling nauseous, and she knew something was horribly wrong.

There have been no further clues about Hammer's identity, powers, or motivations.  Since Claire was the only one to use his nickname...he could be...

...anybody.  ;)

Comment: Captain Hammer!

Comment: We apparently know that he is not anyone who was explicitly named as having met Claire. From the description you give, he cannot be Sylar since he shares Claires haealing power. So that leaves the rest of the world.

Comment: Here is proof that "Hammer" could not be Sylar. On June 5, 2012, the Highland Dream docks in Tarragona, Spain. Peter, Claude, and possibly Sylar rescue a group of eight evos from being lynched in Monaco and take them to the Highland Dream. Claude and Sylar soon disappear, but Peter stays on the barge to help Mohinder take care of the rescued evos. By July 4, one of the evos, who Claire nicknames "Hammer", recovers from his injuries

Answer (score 1):

On the Heroes Wiki, [Hammer](http://heroeswiki.com/Hammer) is listed as their biological father and he was introduced in [Heroes Evolutions: Save the Cheerleader, Destroy the World](http://heroeswiki.com/Save_the_Cheerleader,_Destroy_the_World), although Hiro was mentioned as having raised Nathan and teaching him how to be the new master of time and space throughout the show.

Not much is known about Hammer aside from the fact that he was Claire's Love interest, he is hot tempered, and she gave him his nickname because of the trench-coat he wears (seen in the picture below); he doesn't like it so he calls her blondie.

In episode 13 Melina and Nathan each get something like a tarot card. 
The one says "I Gemelli" or "The Twins" and the other says, "Is Distruttore" or "The Destroyer".

[image]

Melina then meets with her grandmother and she describes finding the card:

> Melina: "I found this. On the card is twins. When I touched it I got this feeling, like someone was watching me. You know what this is don't you?"

Grandma Patrelli:

> "It's a message from your father Melina. It means he's coming back
>   for you and your brother. And this time no one will be able to protect
>   you."

This is who left the card in the diner:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I read that the father was someone called "Hammer".

I tried finding out who Hammer is, and its looking like its just a nickname that Claire gave to Sylar. I'm not sure, but now I can't wait

Comment: oops. i forgot to post that i read that the father was "hammer" :)

Comment: Or maybe he was *a* hammer. Like an evos power was to become a power tool?!? It could happen